# How to code a loop in Java that access a 2D array using the the data stored in another 2D array that contains the adyacent positions of each position

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I have a function that returns all the adyacent positions of a 2D array, something like this:

```
public static int[][] adyacents(int rows, int columns, int offsetRow, int offsetCol) {...}
```

The main array and one example of the adyacent array are the following ones to put an example:

```
char[][] example = {
                {'A', 'B', 'C'},
                {'D', 'E', 'F'},
                {'G', 'H', 'I'}};

int[][] AdyacentsOfA = {
                {0, 1},
                {1, 0},
                {1, 1}};
```

The only thing I need is to make a loop to access the content of all the different adyacent positions of each position of the main array.

Comment: I can't tell from your example how the adjacent array works.  What is the output supposed to look like?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc The main array called "example" is wrtitted by the user in the code, the adyacents function will return a 2D array with al the adyacent positions given the array and the offsets, for example: for example[0][0] will return {{0,1}.{1,0},{1,1}}, for example[1][0] will return {{0,0}.{0,1},{1,1},{2,0}, {2,1} and so on, now i want to make a loop to access the content of each one of the adyacent positions of every position of the array.

Comment: My guess is the return is an `[2][n]` array, where each `n` is a `{row, column`} pair. `n` can have the value  2 (corner), 5 (edge), or 8 (interior).

Comment: I wouldn't use a loop at all.  The largest your adjacent array will be is 8x2.  Create the eight lines and test that each coordinate is inside the bounds with a separate method.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer that is what the adyacents function does, it returns a [n][2] array where each n is a {row, column}, now i want to make a loop to access the positions that the [n][2] array returned in the main array and do the same for all the positions.

Comment: @WizzzStark,so edit your question and add that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand the question.  Here's one way.

```
for (int i = 0; i < adyacentsOfA.length; i++) {
    int row = adyacentsOfA[i][0];
    int column = adyacentsOfA[i][1];
    char c = example[row][column];
    // Process c
 }
```